# How to replace the custom PAGEBREAK tag with div

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I have the document, for example:

```
This is the first line
<br> 
This is the second line 
<br>
This is the third line
```

Now I want to remove the `<br>` and format the text like below,

```
    <DIV ID=PAGINATION-CONTENT>
        This is the first line
    </DIV>
    <DIV ID=PAGINATION-CONTENT>
        This is the second line 
    </DIV>
    <DIV ID=PAGINATION-CONTENT>
       This is the third line
    </DIV>
```

How it can be possible by using jquery?

Comment: you can't have multiple nodes with the same id, use a class instead

Comment: just have the div's clear both sides to create the line break

Comment: @wirey I think the question is about what's the jquery code to replace the `pagebreak` with a div that wraps the paragraph following it (not exactly, but something like that) Mmm... except that there is no `pagebreak` tag? OP, your question needs clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I have used `classes` as IDs must be unique!

```
<p>
  This is the first line
  <br>
  This is the second line
  <br>
  This is the third line
</p>
```

```
var lines = $('p').html().split('<br>')
var divs = '';
$.each(lines, function(i, line) {
    divs += '<div class="PAGINATION-CONTENT">'+line+'</div>';
})

$('p').html(divs)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j9qsx/1/)

Comment: you can use `body` instead of `p` See this: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/j9qsx/8/

Comment: @GLADIATOR You can replace the `p`s with the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` css rules.

Assuming you are talking about an actual page break (i.e. when printing). If not then your question is very unclear.

Comment: I am not talking about CSS rule... okey question is how to replace the custom PAGEBREAK tag with proper DIV but DIV will be end where the pagebreak tag is there & div started if above text no PAGEBREAK tag or PAGEBREAK tag will be there

Comment: @GLADIATOR Can I assume English is not your first language? Because this comment is very hard to understand.